# Extracting text/characters from Xray images using python

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

[image]

I am trying to extract the characters in the x-ray, I have tried using pytesseract to extract but couldn't succeed, I used a canny edge to remove the noise and extract, but still, I am not able to extract the text/chars. Can you please help/guide me to extract the text/chars

Comment: Can you post the image ? I am wondering if the text is in the Overlay Data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tuotrial to locate the text:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/

Then once you locate you can isolate and use tesseract to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a DICOM file, you could use [gdcm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) to get the attribute. It's available on python too.

Answer (score -1):

`pytesseract` should be sufficient, if the file is in 'png' or 'jpg' form.
now suppose image is the name of your image. Please write the below code.

```
from PIL import Image

from pytesseract import image_to_string

import pytesseract 

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

im = Image.open('F:/kush/invert.jpg')

pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
```